# Form is added in solution explorer but cannot be called

Tags: c#, winforms, transfer

As title suggested I have added an existing form to my project named `Payroll` but before I added it to `Payroll` I renamed the `form` to `frmMain` from `Form1` and I changed it's name from it's original project `Samp Prog` while changing it's name it asked me if I would like to change everything related to the said file `Form1` including the `.cs` and `.designer.cs` but every time I call `frmMain` in any other forms exisisting in `Payroll` it does not show in the suggestions.

Comment: so i just change the namespaces from `Samp Prog` to `Payroll`?

Comment: Can you post your the code behind of both files? without methods

Comment: ah your suggestion already worked, i changed the namespaces and it finally showed up in every form thanks by the way

Comment: Great to hear that, just for completeness I add an answer, for future people who has the same problem

Comment: Please try rebuilding the entire project. Also closing and reopening visual studio. Are you receiving any specific build errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that both have the same namespace, or that you are calling it with the whole namespace

Comment: This should much rather be a comment than an answer.